# subsetting values of matrix with a vector (conditions)

Tags: r, subset, extract

I have the following matrices :

```
>  matrix <- matrix(c(1,3,4,NA,NA,NA,3,0,4,6,0,NA,2,NA,NA,2,0,1,0,0), nrow=5,ncol=4)
> n <- matrix(c(1,2,5,6,2),nrow=5,ncol=1)
```

As you can see, for each rows I have

1. multiple NAs - the number NAs is undefined
2. ONE single "0"

I would like to subset the 0 for the values of the n. Intended output below.

```
> output <- matrix(c(1, 3, 4,NA,NA,NA,3,5,4,6,1,NA,2,NA,NA,2,2,1,6,2), nrow=5,ncol=4)
```

I have tried the following

```
subset <- matrix == 0 & !is.na(matrix)
matrix[subset] <- n
#does not give intended output, but subset locates the values i want to change
```

When used on my "real" data i get the following message :

> Warning message: In m[subset] <- n : number of items to replace is not
>   a multiple of replacement length

Thanks

EDIT : added a row to the matrix, as my real life problem is with an unbalanced matrix. I am using Matrices and not DF here, because i think (not sure)that  with very large datasets, R is quicker with large matrices rather than subsets of dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using

```
out1 <- matrix+n[row(matrix)]*(matrix==0)
identical(output, out1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, this works in my "scaled" example. was looking for this

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to replace the values by row, but subsetting is replacing the values by column (and maybe that's not a completely thorough explanation).  Transposing the matrix will get the desired output:

```
matrix <- t(matrix)
subset <- matrix == 0 & !is.na(matrix)
matrix[subset] <- n
matrix <- t(matrix)

setequal(output, matrix)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for this, it does work on the example I provided. I edited my question as my real life data is not a balanced matrix. cheers for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option with `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(matrix == 0, c(n) * (matrix == 0), matrix)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   NA    1    2
#[2,]    3   NA   NA    2
#[3,]    4    3    5   NA
#[4,]   NA    6   NA    2
```

---

```
zero = matrix == 0
identical(ifelse(zero, c(n) * zero, matrix), output)
# [1] TRUE
```